# JS: How to repeatedly reload page, read element values, then click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

Over the last few days, I've been working on a script that interacts with a particular site. A page on the site has a table of values that is randomized every reload.

I've learned that I can load the page with JQuery's $.get( )  method and then use regex to read the values of the elements, but I can't figure out how to press a button on the page.

I'm not sure how I could select an element then call the normal .click( ) method on it, or if that would even work at all.

Basically, what I want to accomplish is:

- Get a new (reloaded) version of the page.
- Read values from an element on the page.
- Click a button on the page.
- Keep repeating previous 3 steps.

How can I make this happen (with or without JQuery)?

EDIT: So it seems this is difficult/impossible to do from another page, but it works if I'm on the page. Knowing that, is there a way that I can repeating reload the page without disrupting the javascript running on it?

Comment: Why can’t you use the `.click()` method? Just make sure that the DOM is ready and then you can find the button and use the method.

Comment: because it is not his side... so no access to the dom

Comment: you can just use grasemonkey or tampermonkey to run your script on any page.

Comment: @Cracker0dks you have “access” to the DOM on any website through the console or GreaseMonkey etc.

Comment: yeah but thats not what Chthonian meant in his question, and u dont wrote it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the buttonpush don't trigger an get/post event, u cant do this. If the button does, you have to simulate it by sending the next get or post with the button parameters. This will get you the expected datas, so no need to refresh.